# Which Debt shall I pay first?

Tags: mortgage, debt, student-loan

I have 2 debts

the first is my mortgage (**$600,000**) on **3.3%** interest rate

and the other is my study loan (**$60,000**) on **7.0%** interest rate

I made savings of **$30,000** I want to use to pay my debts

Which one is better to pay first and why?

Comment: Does interest on one of the loans trigger a tax break? Do you get any assistance in paying the student loan from your employer, or is there a loan forgiveness provision if you work a specific job for a period of years?

Comment: Are you in the US? Is your mortgage fixed rate until paid off or only for first 'x' years?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, congratulations for wanting to pay down debt with the 30k instead of buying a new car...

You should pay the student loan for three reasons:

- It has the highest interest rate, and thus you will save the most interest (even though you are paying *more* interest with the mortgage, the *reduction* in interest will be higher if you pay down the loan with the higher rate)
- It cuts the balance in half, reducing the minimum payment and helping you get rid of it sooner (neither is a huge mathematical benefit but depending on your goals it might help you hit milestones more quickly)
- There is no asset to sell to get rid of the loan - paying it down is the only way to get rid of it (other than taking lower-paying jobs that eventually pay it off for you, or dying). Bankruptcy has recently been added as an option, but it requires that you prove the loan is an undue hardship.

Put this way: If you pay down the mortgage, you'll save about 3.3% of 30,000 or $990 per year in interest (slightly less since the interest decreases as you pay it down). If you pay off the student loan, you'll save 7.0% of 30,000, or **$2,100** per year in interest.

Even if there were tax advantages with one over the other, paying the loan with more than double the interest rate will more than make up for it.

Comment: This answer is assuming long-term fixed rate mortgage (not an unreasonable assumption), and the third bullet is incorrect (assuming US). Student loans can be discharged in bankruptcy and it has become easier to do so in the recent past. The only thing that might change the conclusion is if the loan is nearing the end of it's fixed rate period and about to go adjustable.

Comment: Some student loans can be discharged, but it is a significantly higher bad to get them discharged ("undue hardship") then a regular, especially secured with a mortgage, debt

Comment: I think "dischargeable" is a better term than "bankruptable". And the mortgage isn't really dischargeable, either, since defaulting on it will result in losing the house. Many state have a homestead exemption, but I don't think that that applies to mortgages. If you declare bankruptcy, the only way that helps on your mortgage is if you're underwater.

Comment: And the second bullet point doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Acccumulation you can pay off $30,000 faster than you can pay off $570,000.

Comment: I removed the bankruptcy part (I had forgotten that it was recently added as an option) and changed the third bullet to be about the loan being unsecured. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: @RonJohn So? Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: Agree with Accumulation; this would only matter if there were some inherent advantage to having 1 loan left instead of 2. There may be some psychological advantages to that, which is the foundation of Dave Ramsey’s ideas, but that doesn’t apply to someone with only 2 debts, and it’s mathematically irrelevant.

Comment: Getting rid of one of the loans sooner means that minimum monthly payments are reduced sooner. It doesn't make a difference in the long run, but it could be beneficial for cash flow issues.